# Envío de variables desde PHP a JS

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando mandar una variable desde `PHP` a `JS` de manera que si en la página estoy registrado como administrador, se envíe esta variable y poder generar un `alert` desde `JS`. Para ello estoy intentando utilizar `AJAX` con `jQuery`.

```
<?php
    require_once('../datos/usuariosPDO.php');
    require_once('../negocio/sesiones.php');
    comprobarSesion();

    if ($_SESSION['usuario']['Correo']=='admin@salud.org') {
        $mensaje = 'Alerta de stock';
        $response = array('mensaje' => $mensaje);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

?>
```

Esto para empezar no me gusta porque me muestra en pantalla el echo y no quiero eso. En cuanto a JS el código es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../presentacion/productos.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.mensaje) {
                alert(response.mensaje);
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Los archivos están distribuidos de la siguiente forma, de manera que si no me equivoco, la ruta en `ajax` **../presentacion/productos.php** es correcta.

[image: estructura de archivos]

Tanto `jQuery` como el archivo **alerts.js** están bien referenciados en el documento `PHP` en cuestión, en este caso **productos.php** ya que un `alert` antes de `ajax` funciona.

He probado con **json.encode**, con **echo y dataType:text** pero ambas me muestran el valor en la pagina y la petición `ajax` no hace nada.

La idea es enviar una variable para que `jQuery` sepa que el administrador es el que está registrado y enviar el `alert` solo a él.

Si utilizo **header('Content-Type: application/json');** La pagina ya no se interpreta como `html` y se muestra el `json`.

[image: json]

Comment: ¿Desde cual pagina estas llamando el alerts.js? ¿Que nombre tiene? y como se llama el archivo de la captura con fondo negro? quiero hacerme una idea de la estructura mas completo porque creo ahí puede estar el error.

Comment: Llamo a alerts.js desde productos.php. La captura en negro es productos.php pero se muestra así al intentar hacerlo con header('Content-Type: aplicación/json'). Lo que sí funciona es establecer una etiqueta script con php al final del documento productos.php y meter dentro el codigo JS correspondiente. Porque buscaba es pasar una variable de php a JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Mostrar el `alert` desde el archivo `php`

```
if ($_SESSION['usuario']['Correo']=='admin@salud.org') {
    echo '<script>alert("Alerta de stock");</script>';
}
```

2. Crear un elemento oculto en el archivo `php` y leerlo desde `JS`

```
#Código en productos.php

if ($_SESSION['usuario']['Correo']=='admin@salud.org') {
    echo '<span id="admin" hidden>1</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span id="admin" hidden>0</span>';
}
...
<body>
    <!-- Acá va todo el código HTML... -->
    <!-- ...Y al final se hace la referencia o la llamada al archivo JS -->
    <script src="../ajavascript/alerts.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
//Código en alerts.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let admin = $('#admin').html();
    if (admin == 1){
        alert("Alerta de stock");
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que la llamada al archivo `JS` debe estar al final del documento, antes de cerrar la etiqueta `body` y no en la aparte superior.

Comment: Si, así lo hice. Al final del documento creo la etiqueta script con php y meto dentro el codigo JS. Claro, así funciona, pero quería saber si existe forma de pasar una variable php a JS para no tener en el mismo documento todo mezclado

Comment: El último ejemplo funciona teniendo dos archivos diferentes, uno para `php` y el otro para `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tratas de hacer que productos.php funcione como pagina y que al mismo tiempo muestre los datos en json, hay que separar eso porque así no puedes cargar los datos correctamente, ya que carga el resto del html, ensuciando el json imposibilitando su uso.

Te propongo la siguiente solución, quita el siguiente código de **productos.php**

```php
<?php
    require_once('../datos/usuariosPDO.php');
    require_once('../negocio/sesiones.php');
    comprobarSesion();

    if ($_SESSION['usuario']['Correo']=='admin@salud.org') {
        $mensaje = 'Alerta de stock';
        $response = array('mensaje' => $mensaje);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 ?>
```

Y lo colocas en un archivo nuevo en la misma ruta, por ejemplo **alerta.php**

**alert.js** lo sigues llamando desde productos.php, ademas tendrías que editarlo así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../presentacion/alerta.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.mensaje) {
                alert(response.mensaje);
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Si aun así sigues con problemas, puede que estés omitiendo código y tendrías que mostrar las partes que faltan, ademas de eso te comento que para código es preferible coloques el código a una imagen, es mas fácil para hacer pruebas y evitara te valoren mal.

Comment: Entiendo el planteamiento. El archivo alerts.js coge el JSON de alerts.php, que al estar en otra página no afecta a productos.php. Lo probare, aunque la solución de @DjCrazy creando un span con php me evita crear un archivo extra. En este caso finalmente creo que es la opción más limpia y con menos Código. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido bien el problema, pero puede ser lo siguiente:
Cuando llamas al archivo php, este por defecto devolverá la cabecera text/html de tipo de contenido. Arriba del todo de ese archivo PHP, añade:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

De esta forma en el front se recibirá como json y se parseará automáticamente a objeto.

Comment: he probado como dices también, pero como puedes ver en la reedición de mi pregunta, se acaba mostrando el json y no se interpreta el html. La manera en la que he conseguido hacer lo que quiero, ha sido añadiendo con PHP una etiqueta <script> al final de la página con el código JS  si el usuario es el administrador. La intención era tener  el código separado y pasar una variable de PHP a JS